# Plot solutions of bivariate polynomial equation

Tags: r, plot, equation

How can I plot the solutions of this equation in R?

> (x²+y²-1)³=x²y³

Comment: How would you plot `x * y = x^2 * y^2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- seq(-2, 2, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(-2, 2, length.out = 100)
z <- outer(x, y, function(x,y) (x^2+y^2-1)^3 - x^2*y^3)
contour(x, y, z, levels = 0, drawlabels = FALSE)
```

[image]